# How many NAs in data set

Tags: r, rows, na

I need to know how to find out how many ROWS in my data set contain NA

I also then need a table to show how many ROWS contain NA according to region.

Any help would be much appreciated. TIA

Comment: What have you attempted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you haven't provided any code example picking the airquality dataset.

Try the complete.cases command.

```
table(complete.cases(airquality))   # to count nrows with NA's

table(complete.cases(airquality$Ozone)) # for a specific column count NA's
```

Also look into is.na() functions.